# Using Inverse Trig. Technique

Tags: calculus

$\int$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}}$

Let $x = 2\tan\theta +1$

$dx= 2\sec^2\theta d\theta$

$= \int$$\frac{2\sec^2\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{4\sec^2\theta}}$

$=\int\sec d\theta$

$= \ln(\sec\theta + \tan\theta) + C$

Triangle based off of x substitution: opposite= $x-1$

adjacent=2 and hypotenuse = $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}$

Thus answer $=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}}{2} + \frac{x-1}{2}) + C$

However according to my given solution it should be equal to

$=\ln(\sqrt{x^2-2x+5} + x-1) + C$

I know that this is unfactored form of the polynomial but i do not know why the

2 in my denominator is incorrect.

Comment: both answers are same upto a constant $$=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}}{2} + \frac{x-1}{2}) + C = \ln(\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4} + x-1)  \color{blue}{-\ln(2)} + C $$

Comment: Do you know what the $C$ in the answer denotes?

Comment: Try to use cosh function

Comment: use `\ln, \sec, \sin,... `etc. for $\ln, \sec, \sin,... $ and use `$$...$$` for centre aligned equations and `\\` for newline.For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}}{2} + \frac{x-1}{2}\right) + C=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}+x-1}{2}\right) + C=\ln\left(\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}+x-1\right)-\ln 2 + C=\ln\left(\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}+x-1\right)+C'$$

You should know $\ln ab=\ln a+\ln b$.